# A dog biting a complete binary Christmas tree - expected value, variance

Tags: probability, variance

Professor Macarius bought a complete binary Christmas tree having $2^D - 1$ vertices. Unfortunately, on the Christmas Eve his dog Brutus bit the tree. Each of the edges is bit with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, independently from other edges. Let $X$ be the number of vertices in the remaining tree (connected part containing the tree's tip). 
Count the expected value and variance of $X$.

My solution:
Let $1, 2, ..., 2^D - 1$ be the numbers of the vertices counting from the top left ($1$ is the number of the tip, $2$ is the number of the left son of the tip etc.). Let $X_i$ be a Bernoulli random variable such that $X_i=1$ if vertex no. $i$ is in the remaining part of the tree. $$EX_i = \frac{1}{2}^{\lfloor{log_2{i}}\rfloor}$$
$$X = X_1 + ... + X_{2^D - 1}$$
$$EX = \sum_{i=1}^{2^D - 1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\lfloor log_2 i \rfloor} \le H_{2^D - 1}$$
Is it correct? Can you get a better approximation for $EX$?

How to count the variance? I'm unfortunately unable to count $EX^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expectation can be calculated by saying that there if levels are labelled $0,1,\ldots,D-1$, there are $2^d$ vertices at level $d$ and each of these has probability $\frac1{2^d}$ of staying connected to the tip, so the overall expected number connected is $\sum_d  2^d \frac1{2^d} = D$

Comment: I suspect the variance may be $$\dfrac{(D-1)D(2D-1)}{12}=\frac12\sum_{d=0}^{D-1} D^2$$ so there might be a simple calculation for that too

Comment: Why do you suspect it? I'm unable to solve it.

Comment: @Cachetejack I tried to calculate the variances for $D=1,2,3,4$, getting $0,0.5,2.5,7$ and looked for a simple pattern.  The probabilities themselves were not so simple: for example with $D=4$ I found $P(X=2) =\frac2{2^4}= 0.125$, $P(X=3)=\frac5{2^6}=0.078125$ and $P(X=4)=\frac8{2^6}+\frac{6}{2^8}=0.1484375$ which I thought a mildly surprising pattern